# How to rename multiple folders using spreadsheet?

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory

If I'm on windows 7 and I have a spreadsheet:

```
1, Ant
2, Brown Bear  (note whitespace)
3, Cat
4, Dinosaur
```

And folders

```
C:\Directory\1\
C:\Directory\2\
C:\Directory\4\
```

Is there any way to put in a batch file or a vbs file or whatever the appropriate tool is in that directory that would rename those folders using the spreadsheet? With the final result being:

```
C:\Directory\1 Ant\
C:\Directory\2 Brown Bear\
C:\Directory\4 Dinosaur\
```

So far I have a batch file that will append a string to all the folders in the directory it's run in (be cautious where you run it), but I'd just be using if statements for many, many items. Any suggestions on how to connect it to a csv file?

@echo off

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=,(" %%a in ('dir /a:d /b') do (

    if "%%a" == "10" ( ren "%%a" "%%a Elephant" )
    if "%%a" == "11" ( ren "%%a" "%%a Otter")
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple unclear points in your question (like the names: are they in a spreadsheet or in a .csv file?) so I made some assumptions. Given a names.csv file with this contents:

```
1, Ant
2, Brown Bear
3, Cat
4, Dinosaur
```

The Batch file below achieve the rename you want:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the array of equivalences from names.csv file:
for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in (names.csv) do set "name[%%a]=%%b"

rem Rename the folders:
cd C:\Directory
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /A:D /B') do ECHO ren "%%a" "%%a!name[%%a]!"
```

Previous Batch file just *show* the `ren` commands; if the output looks good, remove the `ECHO` part in order to *execute* the commands.

If names.csv file have a header in the first line, insert "skip=1 " before "tokens" in the first `for /F ...` command.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you're OK with using Powershell this little script could help:

```
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path

Import-Csv "D:\Test\ps\look_up.csv" |`
    ForEach-Object {
        $old = $directorypath + "\" + $_.orig
        if(Test-Path($old)){            
            $newPath = $directorypath + "\" +$_.orig + " " + $_.new
            ren $old $newPath
        }
    }
```

I had folders named `1,2,3` in the same folder as the script and a csv file with the following content:

```
orig, new
1, buga boo
2, bla
3, bu
4, none
```

After running the script the folders were named

```
Name
----
1 buga boo
2 bla
3 bu
```